# What does map' f xs = foldr (\y ys -> (f y):ys) [] xs. mean?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

I'm new to Haskell and I want to understand what this syntax means.
This is the context of the function:

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' f xs = foldr (\y ys -> (f y):ys) [] xs
```

It's defining the map function from the prelude in terms of `foldr`. I'm confused by what `foldr (\y ys -> (f y):ys) [] xs` means. Especially the `(\y ys -> (f y): ys)` part.

In my understanding, `y` is the first value in the list `ys` which is the input and the function `f` is being applied to the `y` value in the list `ys`. I understand these values are taken in the context of pattern matching. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at a simplified definition of `foldr` (adapted from [https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)):

```
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

The second argument passed to `f` (`ys`, in your case) is basically the *result* of folding the rest of the list, without having to explicitly make the recursive call.

We can compare an explicitly recursive definition of `map'`:

```
map' f [] = []
map' f (x:xs) = f x : map' xs
```

to the expansion of your definition of `map'` using equational reasoning.

```
map' f (x:xs)
       -- by definition of map'
   == foldr (\y ys -> f y : ys) [] (x:xs)
       -- by definition of foldr
   == (\y ys -> f y : ys) x (foldr (\y ys -> f y : ys) [] xs)
       -- application of folding function to x...
   == (\ys -> f x : ys) (foldr (\y ys -> f y : ys) [] xs)
       -- ... and then the recursive fold
   == f x : foldr (\y ys -> f y : ys) [] xs
       -- by definition of map'
   == f x : map' f xs
```

Comment: chepner's definitely aware of this, but for OP/other people: the "application of folding function to x" step is actually two _beta reductions_, and you can look that term up if you're still a bit confused.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that description  was misleading around the same time you posted your comment :)

Comment: I've broken that into two distinct steps; I'm undecided whether that's clearer than just applying the function to both arguments at once....

Comment: I think both the original and the current answer are good :) I was just offering up a phrase one can google to find more examples; I think lambdas/beta reduction tend to be confusing to people until they've seen them a few dozen times.